# What does the front end know about HTTP?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, frontend

How does the front end (for example, a website) know what version of HTTP call the connection is?

When client make a API call, how can it know if it's a HTTP 1.1, HTTP 2 or HTTPS?

I am not very clear about how these actually connect to each other.

Answer (score 4):

HTTP 1.1 is designed to be, for the most part, backwards compatible with HTTP 1.0. If an HTTP 1.1 client makes a request to an HTTP 1.0 server, the extra headers will be ignored.

HTTP 2 has [clear instructions](https://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7540.html#discover-http) that require the connection to be initiated via HTTP 1.1 with a request for an upgrade to 2 if it is supported by the server.

HTTPS isn't a version of HTTP. It is HTTP over SSL. **If the URL has an HTTPS scheme**, then the client will make an SSL connection to the server and then talk regular HTTP over that SSL connection.

Answer (score 0):

The client specifies the HTTP version in the request, like this:

```
$ telnet cnn.com 80
Trying 157.166.226.25...
Connected to cnn.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: cnn.com
```

HTTP version 2 is written as `HTTP/2`, but that's a binary protocol and I don't know how to illustrate it here. Regardless, the server sees the version and behaves accordingly.

As for HTTP vs. HTTPS, that is a part of the URL (`http:` vs. `https:`). The browser (or other client) either uses plaintext HTTP, or TLS-wrapped HTTP, depending on the protocol specified in the request.

Comment: "In the case of an HTTP 2 connection, it would instead say HTTP/2" — No, that's wrong. Even if the client knows the server has support for HTTP 2, it has to send a connection preface first. https://httpwg.github.io/specs/rfc7540.html#ConnectionHeader

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, after I wrote that I remembered http/2 is completely different on the wire and edit the answer.